# How do I obtain the current Windows DSC working folder (ie. "\DSC.0")?

Tags: powershell-4.0, dsc

Anyone know how to obtain the current DSC working folder?

On the server, when DSC runs, it generates a folder stucture like the following:

C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Powershell.DSC\2.18.0.0\DSCWork\DSC.0

The only trouble is when DSC gets a new version, it increments the ".X" folder.. However, when DSC runs, there is no clear way how to resolve the current folder from a script block predictably:

```
    Script GetDscCurrentPath
    {
        TestScript = {
            return $false
        }
        SetScript ={
            Write-Verbose (Get-Item 'C:\%path_to_dsc%\FileInsideMyDscAsset.txt')
        }
        GetScript = { @{Result = "GetDscCurrentPath"} }
    }
```

Thoughts? Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DSC Extension does not expose a variable or function to get the current working directory, but since your script / module is in the directory you should be able to use the PSScriptRoot to get the directory.  Here is an example:

```ps1
Write-Verbose -Message "PSScriptRoot: $PSScriptRoot" -Verbose

# Note PSScriptRoot will change when the extension executes
# your configuration function.  So, you need to save the value 
# when your configuration is loaded
$DscWorkingFolder = $PSScriptRoot

configuration foo {

    Script GetDscCurrentPath
    {
        TestScript = {
            return $false
        }
        SetScript ={
            Write-Verbose $using:DscWorkingFolder
        }
        GetScript = { @{Result = $using:DscWorkingFolder} }
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated per the edit that you attempted.  I disagree with the reviewers comments.

Comment: +1 In every others situation I've seen `$scriptPath = Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path` recommended as the way to get the working path. However, inside the DSC engine, `Split-Path` crashes and your method works.

Comment: `$PSScriptRoot` was added in a later version of PowerShell, but it's been there along with DSC.  It is much easier to use too.